# google.cloud translation pdf documents (en to zh), return protobuff.repeated,not write pdf,how use python write pdf?

Tags: google-translate, google-translation-api, google-cloud-translate

python code : en pdf translate zh pdf,but translate result not write pdf
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned object of `response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs` is `<class 'proto.marshal.collections.repeated.Repeated'>` which means it is a list. You need to loop through the `bytes_stream` object then write it to file.

See code snippet below for the implementation:

```
bytes_stream = response.document_translation.byte_stream_outputs

f = open('2_after.pdf', 'wb')
for data in bytes_stream:
    f.write(data)
f.close()
```